# Can I invite volunteers to revise my off topic question become on topic question?

Tags: support, review-queues, questions, edits

Currently my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29914033/struts-2-spring-kerberos-integration) is on hold because of the reason "off topic". I look around SO's help center and read this

off topic

> This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope
>   defined by the community. What's on- and off-topic is not always
>   intuitive, so it may be necessary to reword the question to fit this
>   site's scope after reviewing the community guidelines.

According to this,I understand I can edit this off topic question to on topic question.I already edited as much as I can to become on topic question.But its seems over my maximum writing skill.Can I invite volunteers to revise my off topic question become on topic question?

Comment: The best suggestion I can give you would be to search on google, learn more about it, try it, and then come to Stack Overflow to ask questions ( make sure to include the necessary code ). If you just ask for links and tutorials, it is off topic

Comment: @ArunA.S Any comment beyond googling??

Comment: I'm not familiar with java ( or anything in your question ), so I can't really help you beyond that. The only comment I can give you is get a good book, or ask some of the experts you know, or ask for some help on [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/). But, it may not help you as I know nothing about the topic and thus the information I a am giving you here might be totally useless.

Comment: @ArunA.S Thanks I try by myself. But I open for many opinions that why I ask in SO. But it's seems hopeless :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. First, that's not really how this site works. You ask questions and, if they're on-topic, the community answers them. It's not the community's job to figure out what your question should be.

More importantly, your question is hopelessly off-topic. Requests for recommendations for tools, plugins, etc., are always off-topic. Nothing in your question currently asks for an answer to an on-topic question.

*Some* off-topic questions can be reworded to be on-topic. This is not one of them.

Comment: Thank for answering this.I need some starting points for SSO integration for that kind of application.That's why I ask about concept, ideas or resources links that are especially for busy SO answerer because I don't want to waste their precious time.

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye that's very thoughtful of you, but doesn't change the fact that it's off-topic here. If you don't even know where to start, you are not ready to ask on SO.

Comment: @jonrsharpe huh?It looks like "discrimination". :(

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye how so? The same rules apply to *everyone*. SO isn't **and never could be** the right place for *every* question, and there is clear guidance: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, etc.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Could you finish to read my required scenario of that off topic question? Do you understand what i mean on that question? If not I try my writing skill and come back again.

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye yes, I've read it, and I agree with this answer's assessment: it is *"hopelessly off-topic"*. It is not a language problem, and cannot be fixed by editing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe ok thanks for comments. But I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694975/choosing-kerberos-spnego-java-library-for-web-application-single-sign-on. It may be what i want but need to test for sure.

Comment: @SaiYeYanNaingAye: Thanks for drawing that old question to the community's attention. It's been dealt with.

Answer (score 8):

It's not your writing skill. While you could have articulated the question a bit clearer, the fundamental premise of it boiled down to something that is categorically off-topic for the site, recommendations for a library or other external resource.

***I know that it seems crazypants that you can't go to a site all about programming and ask someone what library might work best for you.***

We used to entertain those sorts of questions and they just didn't go well. Most would get one-line terse answers with little more than a link, they didn't age well, and they didn't really *help* anyone after some months had passed.

Now, to your question - you *can* invite people to help you get the question you *intended* to become a reality. The best way to do this is to put as much effort into it as you can, and make sure [it's not off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) to begin with. Indicate in your question that English isn't your first language, and that you'd welcome any help editors would like to give.

Then, *stay around*, monitor your question, address comments, provide additional explanation. If the question *could* be good, folks *will* help you make it good. It happens all the time, despite how frequently you see stuff that's been put on-hold.

You've got (as far as I can tell) the skills needed to get your questions to the point that others see value in them and want to help make them better, where you stumbled a bit on this one wasn't checking to ensure it was on-topic (or not really saying much about how that might not apply in your case within the question itself).

Comment: ok I understood. I doubt my writing skill is hard to understand about that question then I ask this for meta. Now my head is clear, it is not depend on my writing skill :D. By the way, thanks for your answer.